# Taking snapshots of reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've created a snapshot of my report in order to improve the performance. However, it appears that it's only using the snapshot on the default values for the report. If I change the values, it appears that it's calling the procedure again (?) or rendering the report again.

The report has a dataset which calls a procedure (no input parameters), which can be filtered using the input parameters.

The snapshot has been created using the Snapshot Options and Processing Options. Any ideas what I need to do in order for the report to use the snapshot all the time?

Answer (score 0):

That is basically how snapshots work - they are a point-in-time copy of the report results taken with the default parameter values. If you change the parameters on the report then SSRS will not use the snapshot because the report results could be different.

It sounds like your report is always returning all data from the procedure, which is then filtered at report rendering time based on the parameter values. This is not a good design and is probably the reason for your report performance problems. Try modifying the procedure to accept parameters and passing these from the report - this way the procedure only returns as much data as is necessary to display in the report and the report server does not have to do filtering when rendering the report.